# Does the Bounty Hunter Track ability grant true sight of the affected unit to all allies?

Tags: dota-2

Does the Bounty Hunter Track ability grant true sight of the affected unit to all allies or is the Bounty Hunter the only one that can see it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your vision is shared with all of your allies, so yes, your allies can see invisible units with Track on them.

Answer (score 2):

Also it might be worth noting that your entire team gains the Tracked target's vision as well.

For example, Nightstalker has full night vision and this becomes unobstructed (like a flying unit's) with a scepter. If a Nightstalker with scepter is tracked, then your entire team can see everything he sees (i.e. a huge AOE).

Comment: This answer would fit much better with the Q&A format of this site, if it were a comment!